# Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [XXX] on this ManagedType

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract net.sdake.res1.entities.test.TestEntity net.sdake.res1.dao.TestDao.findByShopId(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [shopId] on this ManagedType [net.sdake.res1.entities.test.TestEntity]

```java
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "shop_id")
    protected Long shopId;

    public Long getShopId() {
        return shopId;
    }

    public void setShopId(Long shopId) {
        this.shopId = shopId;
    }
}

@Entity
public class TestEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Long name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Long name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "shop_id")
    @Override
    public Long getShopId() {
        return shopId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setShopId(Long shopId) {
        this.shopId = shopId;
    }
}

public interface TestDao extends JpaRepository<TestEntity,Long>{

    TestEntity findByShopId(Long shopId);

}
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract net.sdake.res1.entities.test.TestEntity net.sdake.res1.dao.TestDao.findByShopId(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [shopId] on this ManagedType [net.sdake.res1.entities.test.TestEntity]

Start-up error reporting

Comment: Take a look here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions , example 63. public interface MappedTypeRepository<T extends AbstractMappedType>
  extends Repository<T, Long> is different than your repository. Try it, maybe it will work.

Comment: @sdake please make your solution an answers so others may profit from it.